# cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError) - rails c - was working 10 minutes ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rails-console, ruby-2.3

I have no Idea what has gone wrong here. `rails c` was working 10 minutes ago perfectly. I loaded into my production environment and for some reason the console didn't recognize one of my database tables. I exited and attempted again a few more times with no luck in getting it to recognize the table, then I try one more time and poof, no more rails c.

I have tried a few times now uninstalling bundler, my ruby version, `rvm cleanup all`, and more everything that shows online is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. ruby 2.3.1, rails 5, bundler-1.13.6

Comment: Probably not enough information to diagnose. Some suggestions. Pending migration or removed a migration? Is rails aware of the correct environment? i.e. RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was a rails 5 problem.

`bundle config –delete bin
rails app:update:bin`

Rails 5 uses different binaries than any other rails version and thus answers for other rails versions were not giving me expected results. This command rebuilt the binary files in order for me to properly execute `rails c`

Answer (score 0):

Try with **gem install bundler** to load bundle
Might help it !!

Answer (score 0):

Need to check with migrations in production

```
rake db:migrate
```

after that execute bundle command

```
bundle install
```

Or check with this command to run rails console in production

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails console  #rails 4
rails console production            #rails 3
```